# Naming convention for an Entity and it's Protocol (Interface)

Tags: swift

**What is the accepted naming convention when creating an Entity class and Protocol that describes it's interface (not it's behaviour) ?**

We have been encouraged down the route of naming Protocols according to behaviours
However, in the case of an entity, you might what to mandate it's interface (using a Protocol).

*Example*
**RecipeKit** is a framework that acts as a logic framework for managing Recipes.
`Recipe` is a Protocol .. and it's what the consumer would expect to interact with

```
protocol Recipe {
  var name: String { get }
  var methods: [String] { get }
  ...
}
```

.

***back to the question***

> What is the accepted naming convention when creating an Entity class and Protocol that describes it's interface (not it's behaviour) ?

is the following accepted ?
based on having seen `_<Entity>` in the debugger (and how we used to do ObjC .. pre-ARC)

```
class _Recipe: Recipe {
  private var name: String
  private var methods: [String]
}
```

.

.. as far as I can tell, the following isn't appropriate :
1. because it allows read/write access

```
class Recipe {
  public var name: String
  public var methods: [String]
}
```

2. not very Swift-like

```
class RecipeImpl: Recipe {
  private var name: String
  private var methods: [String]
}
```

3. not very Swift-like (2)

```
class RecipeEntity: Recipe {
  private var name: String
  private var methods: [String]
}
```

4. Consumer of RecipeKit would expect a `Recipe` (not `RecipeProtocol`).

```
class Recipe: RecipeProtocol {
  private var name: String
  private var methods: [String]
}
```

Comment: I would go with option 4 `RecipeProtocol` based on some of Swift's built in types like StaticArrayProtocol` for example

Comment: Thank you @donnywals .. I'm trying to think about how that would look in a project that uses `RecipeKit`, at the call site. Don't you think interacting with a `RecipeProtocol` is less friendly than `Recipe` (as a Protocol)

Comment: Not necessarily, especially if that means the conrete type would become something like `ConcreteRecipe`

Comment: Ok, so if the Implementation is called `ConcreteRecipe` .. then the Protocol could be called `Recipe` .. that's correct, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. 
Btw: I'm voting to close this question because it's mostly opinion-based

Comment: Seeing that people are posting answers on this made me realize that this question doesn't fit the guidelines of stackoverflow, hence my realization that this is an opinion based question and should be flagged as such. If you want to have a discussion on naming, the Swift forum is probably a better platform: http://forums.swift.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I like the solution presented in this tutorial: [Clean Architecture for SwiftUI](https://nalexn.github.io/clean-architecture-swiftui/).

```
protocol Recipe {
  var name: String { get }
  var methods: [String] { get }
  ...
}
```

```
class RealRecipe: Recipe {
  private var name: String
  private var method: [String]
}
```

This is just one of the possibilities but it allows you to use `Recipe` (instead of `RecipeProtocol`) in other places which may be more readable. But in the end it's just a matter of preferences.

*Note*

If you're concerned about public write access in:

```
class Recipe {
  public var name: String
  public var method: [String]
}
```

you can use `private(set)` to make write *private* and read *public*.

Comment: Hi @pawello2222 .. thank you. I'm in favour of your initial suggestion, i.e. having an alternative non-public facing classname (I chose `_Recipe`, you chose `RealRecipe`) As you say `Recipe` is a more readable than `RecipeProtocol`

Comment: The `private(set)` approach wouldn't work for RecipeKit (as a Framework) .. would it ?

Comment: @MDMonty I just proposed `private(set)` as a note in case you'd need it in the future. I believe frameworks should rely on protocols.